# How do I display action data in a JSP?

Tags: java, collections, struts2, struts

I am using an `<s:iterator>`  tag in my JSP to display a `List` of people objects.

I tried creating `ListOfPersons` as a `List` in the action class, along with a getter and setter. I am still unable to display the data--how can I do it?

```
<s:iterator value="ListOfpersons" status="stat">
```

When I tried printing the size of list I am getting zero.

Comment: i am still not sure which tag are you talking about? is it a custom tag or its the `<s:iterator>` and please post code of action class as well details about the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, you are having problem with expressing list using OGNL on JSP pages. You should name fields with `YourListName[index].property` format. Then OGNL will understand that you have a list called `YourListName` and its element at `index` have `property` with value which is on its input.

Please see example below:

```
<table>
<s:iterator value="ListOfpersons" status="status">
<tr>
   <td><s:textfield name="ListOfpersons[%{#status.index}].firstname"/></td>
   <td><s:textfield name="ListOfpersons[%{#status.index}].lastname"/></td>
   <td><s:textfield name="ListOfpersons[%{#status.index}].age"/></td>
   <td><s:textfield name="ListOfpersons[%{#status.index}].sex"/></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
</table>
```

Comment: I believe the List object can easily be refereed in your JSP if they are not Map.Since the Object will be placed on the top of stack and you can refer it easily like `firstName` etc

Comment: Please refer the example in the doc. http://www.struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/iterator.html

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: store the information in the request and access it in the jsp.

Longer Answer:

1. Create some objects in the servlet (in your case, the action).
2. Store the objects in some JSP scope ([HttpServletRequest.setAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)).
3. Forward (dispatch) the request to the JSP page (this is just struts config, you are already doing this).
4. In the JSP page, reference the variables (perhaps using a c:out tag or just use an EL expression in the JSP page text).

Some code (struts 1.x):

```
class Blah extends Action
{
  public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  {
    ... do stuff
    request.setAttribute("Blammy", "Blammy Value");
    ... return some ActionForward.
  }
}
```

In a JSP:

```
<span>The value of the Blammy variable is this here thing: ${Blammy}</span>
```

or

```
<span>The value of the Blammy variable is this here thing: <c:out value="${Blammy}"/></span>
```

Once you have the basic concepts down, just set a request attribute with the `List` in question and access it using the iterator tag in your JSP.